# PyCuda libcurand import issue

Tags: nvidia, cuda

There are many issues similar to mine, but solutions to those do not work for me. My speculation is that due having previously installed cuda-5.5 something is still set to that version, but no idea what exactly.

Below: Update after symbolic linking.

Basically, when I run in Python

```
>>> from pycuda.driver import autoinit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/dawid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycuda/driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pycuda._driver import *  # noqa
ImportError: libcurand.so.5.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My setting:

```
.bashrc:
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
```

Confirmation:

```
dawid@junkyard:~$ ldconfig -p | grep libcurand
    libcurand.so.8.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcurand.so.8.0
    libcurand.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcurand.so

dawid@junkyard:~$ ll /usr/local/cuda*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   19 Mar 15 10:13 /usr/local/cuda -> /usr/local/cuda-8.0/

/usr/local/cuda-8.0:
{bins, docs, nvcc, etc.}
```

NVCC version:

```
dawid@junkyard:~$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61
```

After performing symbolic linking there seem to be additional trait in the trail. Now Python complains about `undefined symbol` to which Google suggests taking care of Boost library. Any thoughts?

```
>>> import pycuda.autoinit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/dawid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycuda/autoinit.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pycuda.driver as cuda
  File "/home/dawid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycuda/driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pycuda._driver import *  # noqa
ImportError: /home/dawid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycuda/_driver.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev
```

Comment: Perhaps you could just make a link from `libcurand.so.5.5` to `libcurand.so.8.0`.

Comment: @Jos Initially I considered this, but thought about doing it properly and not in a hacky way. But I did this and it added extra clue. Seems there's some mismatch with Boost lib.